# How to implement a table design in which a single 'Group' table can contain references to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

So I'm currently designing a database which contains transactional data, and each transaction is associated with an account. I am also writing an application that can run reports on data in these transactions.

I have an Account table which has the following fields (simplified)-

```
Account_ID
Account_Name
Company_ID (This is nullable - not every account has to have a company)
```

As you can probably guess from above; I also have a Company table- A Company can be associated with many Accounts and the tables are linked. The Company table has the following fields:

```
Company_ID
Company_Name
```

What I'm trying to work out is the best way to have a 'Groups' table. I would like to be able to group together both Accounts as well as Companies- and even have a group which contains both Companies and Groups together.

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is if someone runs a report and selects a Group as the criteria, then transactions are returned from all accounts that are in the group as well as those with a reference to any companies in the group - if that makes sense?

At the moment I'm thinking one 'Group' table:

```
Group_ID
Group_Name
```

And two 'many to many' tables-

GroupsAccounts:

```
Group_ID
Account_ID
```

GroupsCompanies:

```
Group_ID
Company_ID
```

And having the application do a union query against those two tables in the background which I can then use in a second query but this seems a rather messy way to do it - I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before and has any suggestions on a more 'correct' way of doing it?

I've been googling around to try and find any examples of this- but I haven't found anything like I'm trying to achieve! Whether there's a good reason for that I shall no doubt see from your responses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the idea to have all accounts within a company display if it's a company? e.g. Group 1 has company X and account Y. Company X has accounts A, B, C. If someone queries for members of Group 1, will they see A, B, C, Y or Company X, Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, I would recommend

Account Table

```
Account_ID
Account_Name
Company_ID (nullable)
Group_ID (nullable)
```

Company Table

```
Company_ID
Company_Name
Group_ID (nullable)
```

Group Table

```
Group_ID
Group_Name
```

This structure assumes that, while a company may have multiple accounts, and accounts may exist without a company, accounts/companies will not be linked to multiple groups.

EDIT: If accounts/companies can be in multiple groups then get rid of the Group_ID reference columns and use the below table.

AccountCompanyToGroup Table

```
Group_ID
Account_ID
Company_ID
```

Comment: Thanks! Accounts and Companies would need to be in multiple groups and a single many-to-many table with both Company and Account ID's is a lot more simple than what I was thinking.